# Question about aProof using simple functions.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

[image]

Im confused about the following proof: why is $E_j$ and $F_k$ the union of intersections? Why is the union of $E_j$ and $F_j$ equal to $X$?

Comment: Look back a couple pages in the text where the *standard representation* of a simple function is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since any $x\in X$ lies in one $E_j$ and $F_k$, there is
$$
\bigcup_{j=1}^nE_j=\bigcup_{k=1}^mF_k=X
$$
Moreover
$$
E_j=E_j\cap X=E_j\cap \bigcup_{k=1}^mF_k=\bigcup_{k=1}^m(E_j\cap F_k)
$$
$$
F_k=F_k\cap X=F_k\cap \bigcup_{j=1}^nE_j=\bigcup_{j=1}^n(E_j\cap F_k)
$$